# How Do I Remove Plastic Shelf Support Holder Pin

Tags: cabinets, closet, custom-cabinetry

I've been trying to remove this support bracket so I can install a closet rod instead, but can't seem to find out how to do so. Can someone help me out please? Thanks!

[image: shelf support bracket]

Answer (score 3):

This is a **thread-cam locking shelf support**. You can undo it by turning the screw a quarter turn counter clockwise, then lifting up on the shelf.

[image: thread can locking support]

Comment: Or you could if the head hadn't been stripped anyway...

Comment: He's not wanting to remove the shelf. He wants to remove the bracket.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the locking cam is missing. You will have to seperate the parts and then you should be abke to slip a thin flathead screwdriver below the mechanism (from the side). The cam lock is a press fit into the hole so it will resist some but jf you are careful and take your time you will be able to get this out.